# parse an array into smaller list of text elements

Tags: python

I am very new to python but if you have a list of text lines say

```
["rr tt hh", "qq pp ll"]
```

how can you further split each element of the list into an array based on the space character between the elements. The desired outcome is
a new array with the following

```
list 1 position ["rr", "tt", "hh"]
     2 position ["qq", "pp", "ll"]
```

and so on

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it:

```
>>> l = ["rr tt hh", "qq pp ll"]
>>> list(map(str.split, l))
[['rr', 'tt', 'hh'], ['qq', 'pp', 'll']]
```

You can remove the `list()` call if you're happy with an iterable instead of the outer list.

Another way to do it is

```
>>> [el.split() for el in l]
[['rr', 'tt', 'hh'], ['qq', 'pp', 'll']]
```

Comment: hi, that works fine but after this operation when I type in l[0][0] it does not return rr but just r. Can you pls explain how to access individual elements within the sublist?

Comment: @user3149650: `l` remains unchanged and still contains the original list. You need to assign the result of the code in the answer to some variable, and then use that variable.

Answer (score 2):

The string `split()` method splits a string into a list of substrings based on a delimiter. If no delimiter is specified, it defaults to a space `' '`.

```
>>> best_list_ever = ['rr tt hh', 'qq pp ll']
>>> best_list_ever[0]
'rr tt hh'
>>> best_list_ever[0].split()
['rr', 'tt', 'hh']
>>> best_list_ever[1].split()
['qq', 'pp', 'll']
```

@NPE's first method is most concise, but using this knowledge you can do:

```
[x.split() for x in best_list_ever]
```